# Is there any screen recorder with zoom functionality?

Tags: screen, capture

I have Kazam as screen recorder, but it does not have real-time zoom functionality. On youtube, I saw some videos recorded under ubuntu and they are zooming in-out while recording. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On KDE, you can use the Meta (Windows) key and "+/-" to zoom in and out to the desktop. As long as you have a screen recorder such as recordmydesktop or SimpleScreenRecorder, you should be able to capture it just fine.

I'm not aware yet of a screen recorder that zooms with its own software, but with SimpleScreenRecorder you have a lot of options such as a rectangle, window or screen to record and 'follow the cursor'.

Comment: That's a wonderful info. I will check it and let you know.

Comment: Update: Unfortunately Meta and +/- does not seem to work anymore. I think they disabled this feature.

Comment: @wakeup Perhaps the hotkeys got deleted? If you look under `System Settings` -> `Desktop Effects` -> `Zoom` options, are the hotkeys set to "Meta+-" and "Meta+="?

Comment: thanks! Yes that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try GTK record My Desktop.

> GTK record My Desktop is a desktop session recorder for GNU/linux that
>   attemps to be easy to use, yet also effective at it's primary task.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop
```

Or just click [**GTK record My Desktop** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-recordmydesktop/).

**Note**:You can replicate zooming in and out by left click and dragging on the preview window.

Comment: Is it possible to zoom in and out real-time while recording?

Comment: I haven't tried that, so I can't say.

Comment: @Mitch if you didn't tried. Why are you answering this thread? Please answer only when you are 100% accurate on what you say!

Comment: @AnbuselvanRocky It does have zoom, but I haven't tried the software personally.

Comment: @AnbuselvanRocky No . this recorder can not zoom while recording